# Simulating Co-Integrated Assets

Tags: monte-carlo, correlation, econometrics, cointegration, random-walk

I know how to simulate correlated returns, but I do not know how to simulate Co-Integrated assets. I would like to simulate a co-integrated time series where the Beta Co-Efficient is not constant, but rather has some degree of drift. An equation or model for doing so would be very helpful, thanks very much Quant SE!

Comment: If $\beta$ is drifting, can you still say the series are cointegrated? The standard definition of cointegration has a constant beta. (But probably it could be generalized.)

Comment: While you are correct, i have found time series can be co-integrated for periods of time before a change in volatility affects the $\beta $

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured it out, and kinda feel dumb. It appears It could be solved by multiplying one time series by the beta co-efficient, and having a random walk model the drift of the beta co-efficient, thus a stationary time series could be contrived by the two co-integrated assets.

I am not for sure however, so if I am wrong please correct me.